# Признак конца последовательности в IEnumerator<T>

Tags: java, c#, .net, framework, интерфейс

На мой взгляд метод `bool MoveNext()` нарушает один из принципов SOL**I**D т.к. совмещает в себе метод перехода к следующему элементу и получение признака достижения конца последовательности. Из-за этого возникают проблемы, когда итератор применяется не в простейшем случае в одном цикле foreach, а как аргумент во вложенных вызовах методов. Т.е. используясь во внешнем методе, передается во внутренний, который вызывает `MoveNext()`. Получается, что об окончании последовательности узнает только внутренний метод, а внешний об этом никак не сможет узнать, кроме как в возвращаемом параметре из внутреннего. Но не передавать же `bool` из каждого вызываемого метода! Это сделает код просто ужасающим. Намного логичнее было бы в `IEnumerator` сделать еще одно свойство признака конца. Тем более подобная информация фактически доступна всегда в самом классе итератора и возвращается в методе перемещения.

Пример:

```
public class Parser
{
    void Parse(IEnumerator<char> enumerator)
    {
        // Допустим есть последовательности букв, разделенных пробелами
        enumerator.Reset();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(enumerator.Current)) // пробелы пропускаем
                ParseWord(enumerator); // не понятно в каком положении последовательность
            // Далее должна быть обработка итератора и анализ enumerator.Current
        }
    }

    void ParseWord(IEnumerator<char> enumerator)
    {
        // читаем пока буквы
        while (char.IsLetter(enumerator.Current))
        {
            // ...
            // если при переходе встретили конец последовательности, выходим
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                break;
                // Отсюда начнутся проблемы, т.к.выйдя из метода,
                // теряется информация о конце последовательности.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Как можно заметить, при выходе из метода ParseWord возможны 2 ситуации - либо мы находимся на символе, следующем за словом, либо за словом мы перешли на конец последовательности. Метод Parse не может вызвать MoveNext(), т.к. иначе потеряет символ, а при обращении к enumerator.Current рискует получить исключение. Можно было бы подумать, что по исключению можно определять конец последовательности, но это не так. Во-первых исключение `InvalidOperationException` может возникнуть по иной причине, а во-вторых в случае с массивом оно будет, а в случае с `List<T>` или `string` - нет.

Так же хочу заметить, что в Java, насколько понимаю, ситуация не особо лучше. Там идет совмещение метода перехода и получения самого элемента:

`Interface Iterator<E>`
-`boolean hasNext()` - Returns true if the iteration has more elements. (In other words, returns true if next would return an element rather than throwing an exception.)
-`E next()` - Returns the next element in the iteration. Throws: NoSuchElementException - iteration has no more elements.

Аналогично в примере выше в случае с Java мы приобретем информацию о конце последовательности, но зато потеряем возможность проанализировать сам элемент.

В качестве решения данной проблемы видел создание шаблонного класса-обертки для произвольного итератора, который будет отлавливать и сохранять возвращаемое из `MoveNext()` значения с последующим предоставлением в виде свойства.

В идеале хотелось бы иметь это:

```
public interface IEnumerator
{
    object Current { get; }
    bool MoveNext();
    bool HasValue { get; } // то же что и MoveNext, но без перемещения
    void Reset();
}
```

А вопрос в том, действительно ли тут существует архитектурная проблема интерфейса или может быть все-таки существует какое-то решение, позволяющее применять итератор во многих вложенных методах, не передавая при этом значение, получаемое из `MoveNext()`?

---

@VladD: Извиняюсь, но про кэширование не совсем понял. Разбираться долго не стал, а поняв, что скорее всего мы говорим о разном, решил потратить время на свой пример. Точнее даже 2 примера. 1ый с расширенным энумератором и 2ой со стандартным. И какого же было удивление, что в итоге они оказались практически одинаковыми - всего 3 отличия.

```
// Внимание!
// Допущение: вложенный энумератор должен управляться только логикой класса-обертки и не должен учавствовать в других операциях.

// Допустим в интерфейсе итератора существует еще одно свойство
public interface IEnumeratorEx<out T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    // Признак конца последовательности
    // Он же то, что возвращает MoveNext()
    // Он же, означающий наличие значения, которое можно получить
    bool HasValue { get; }
}

// Класс с расширенным энумератором (+HasValue)
public class FilteringEnumeratorEx<T> : IEnumeratorEx<T>
{
    IEnumeratorEx<T> wrapped; // Оригинальная последовательность, подлежащая фильтрации
    Func<T, bool> filter; // Фильтр

    public T Current
    {
        get
        {
            // Если вложенный итератор не пройден до конца, значит текущий элемент был найден,
            // отфильтрован и должен быть возвращен
            if (HasValue)
                return wrapped.Current;
            else
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Энумератор достиг конца. Значение не может быть получено.");
        }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current { get { return Current; } }

    public bool HasValue { get { return wrapped.HasValue; } }

    public FilteringEnumeratorEx(IEnumeratorEx<T> wrapped, Func<T, bool> filter)
    {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (!HasValue)
            return false;
        while (wrapped.MoveNext() && !filter(wrapped.Current))
            ;
        return HasValue;
    }

    public void Reset() { wrapped.Reset(); }

    public void Dispose() { wrapped.Dispose(); }
}

// Класс со стандартным энумератором
public class FilteringEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    IEnumerator<T> wrapped; // Оригинальная последовательность, подлежащая фильтрации
    Func<T, bool> filter; // Фильтр

    // Поскольку вложенный энумератор не имеет отдельного признака конца, кэшируем последнюю MoveNext()
    // Иными словами, изобретаем костыли
    // Хотя, раз уж есть такое полезное свойство, то почему бы его не выставить наружу, пусть пользуются.
    public bool HasValue { get; private set; } // 1 отличие

    public T Current
    {
        get
        {
            // Если вложенный итератор не пройден до конца, значит текущий элемент был найден,
            // отфильтрован и должен быть возвращен
            if (HasValue)
                return wrapped.Current;
            else
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Энумератор достиг конца. Значение не может быть получено.");
        }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current { get { return Current; } }

    public FilteringEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> wrapped, Func<T, bool> filter)
    {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
        this.filter = filter;
        HasValue = true; // -1 элемент всегда должен позволять шагнуть дальше // 2 отличие
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (!HasValue) // Если предыдущая MoveNext вернула false, значит ушли в конец
            return false; // - вернем признак конца.
        while ((HasValue = wrapped.MoveNext()) && !filter(wrapped.Current)) // 3 отличие
            ;
        return HasValue;
    }

    public void Reset() { wrapped.Reset(); }

    public void Dispose() { wrapped.Dispose(); }
}
```

Могу сделать вывод, что отсутствие в обертываемом итераторе свойства HasValue не особо чем-то мешает добавить его в обертку. По сложности разницы практически нет.

---

Думаю стоит объяснить какой из принципов нарушен на мой взгляд.

*Принцип разделения интерфейса* (англ. Interface Segregation Principle, ISP). Клиенты не должны зависеть от методов, которые они не используют. Много интерфейсов, специально предназначенных для клиентов, лучше, чем один интерфейс общего назначения. Слишком «толстые» интерфейсы необходимо разделять на более маленькие и специфические, чтобы клиенты маленьких интерфейсов знали только о методах, которые необходимы им в работе. В итоге, при изменении метода интерфейса не должны меняться клиенты, которые этот метод не используют.

Данный принцип, думаю, обычно воспринимают касательно интерфейса, как interface в языке программирования. Но если вдуматься, то этот принцип намного более общий и касается интерфейса взаимодействия, чем является так же любой метод, функция и даже целая система. Мне даже кажется, что на самом деле это все тот же *принцип единственной обязанности* (Single responsibility principle). Единственной ответственностью должен обладать не только объект, но и его интерфейс взаимодействия. В то же время каждый метод этого интерфейса в свою очередь так же должен иметь единственную ответственность. Любую сущность следует дробить настолько мелко, насколько это возможно, но не более того.

В интерфейсе взаимодействия с итератором должны быть только те методы, которые касаются его работы. Для этого нужно иметь возможность получать элементы, перебирать их (продвижение по ним), а так же получать информацию о том, закончили мы свой перебор или нет. Далее дробить уже не получится, т.к. удаление любой из возможности сделает работу с интерфейсом невозможной.

Теперь надо спроектировать то, как использовать данные возможности энумератора. Возможны варианты:

```
// Простой enumerator
public interface ISimpleEnumerator
{
    // получить текущий элемент
    object Current { set; }
    // продвинуться дальше
    void MoveNext();
    // проверить наличие текущего элемента
    bool HasValue { get; }
}

// C# enumerator
public interface ICSharpEnumerator
{
    object Current { get; }
    // попытка переместиться на следующий элемент
    bool MoveNext();
}

// Java enumerator
public interface IJavaEnumerator
{
    // остались ли еще впереди элементы
    bool HasNext { get; }
    object Next();
}

// Super enumerator
public interface ISuperEnumerator
{
    // пытаемся получить следующий элемент
    // возвращает признак его получения и сам элемент
    bool MoveNext(out object current);
}

// Все тесты предполагают нахождение итератора в -1 позиции
// т.е. перед первой попыткой чтения.
// В начальном состоянии доступ к любому методу/свойству
// кроме MoveNext некорректен и скорее всего должн вызывать исключение.
public class TestClass
{
    void SimpleEnumeratorTest(ISimpleEnumerator e)
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            e.MoveNext();
            if (!e.HasValue)
                break;
            var x = e.Current;
        }
    }
    void CSharpEnumeratorTest(ICSharpEnumerator e)
    {
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            var x = e.Current;
        }
    }
    void JavaEnumeratorTest(IJavaEnumerator e)
    {
        while (e.HasNext)
        {
            var x = e.Next();
        }
    }
    void SuperEnumeratorTest(ISuperEnumerator e)
    {
        object x;
        while (e.MoveNext(out x))
        {
            // use x
        }
    }
}
```

Как видно, возможности у каждого из 4-ех энумераторов одинаковы, но отличие в том, как спроектирован интерфейс взаимодействия с каждым из них. Если следовать принципу единой ответственности или же принципу разделения интерфейсов, то каждый из методов так же должен быть элементарен, но не более. Т.о. этим принципам удовлетворяет простой энумератор из 3-х методов/свойств, а наиболее нарушает их ISuperEnumerator с всего 1им методом.

По-началу может показаться, что всего 1 метод это очень удобно, но на практике наверняка окажется, что начнет возникать куча проблем из-за того, что в разных местах алгоритма будут требоваться разные данные, получаемые из метода MoveNext и т.о. придется все время их кэшировать и таскать за собой. В пределах одного метода это может не вызвать трудностей, а когда будет затронут стек вызовов, вот тогда то они проявятся в полной мере, т.к. видимости локальных переменных будут пропадать, а получить их заново из интерфейса будет невозможно. В итоге будет сооружен адаптер, приводящий этот супер-интерфейс в простейший-интерфейс. На самом деле это костыль.

Если обратить внимание на всякого рода API, то можно увидеть, что чаще всего каждое взаимодействие делается как можно более мелким и элементарным. Вот именно в этом и проявляется принцип ISP (много интерфейсов, специально предназначенных для клиентов, лучше, чем один интерфейс общего назначения). Его так же можно было бы записать в следующем виде: много методов/функций, специально предназначенных для клиентов, лучше, чем один метод/функция общего назначения.

Хотя SRP и ISP выглядят по-разному, но на самом деле основополагающий принцип у них один и тот же - дробление системы для достижения Low coupling (Слабое зацепление) и High cohesion (Высокая степень связанности), см. GRASP. Основой же является цель упростить систему, посредством уменьшения количества связей в ней.

Не претендую на истину, всего лишь высказал свое мнение.

Comment: к сожалению, комментарии не переносяться - - наличие свойства HasNext потребует от итератора (от всех его реализаций!) возможности получения этого свойства без извлечения Next из реального источника. Что, во многих случаях, затруднительно - напрмер, при получении данных из базы. При этом почти весь существующий код (клиенты текущей реализации) отлично работает без HasNext . А вы ради одного клиента (одного случая) предлагаете расширить базовый интерфейс, заставив всех клиентов зависеть от более толстого интерфейса, что нарушает isp.

Comment: " На счет ISP я не воспринимаю буквально интерфейс, как interface. Интерфейсом может являться и один метод и все, что угодно. Вот я его и дроблю на более мелкие методы. Вместо 1ого более общего метода делаю 2 более специализированных." - а стоило бы воспринимать интерфейс именно как "публичный интерфейс класса" == набор методов. Дело в том, что ваше "особенное" восприятие интерфейса искажает принцип ISP до противоположного. И именно из-за этого вы при его применении получаете обратный эффект - вместо получения отдельных, небльших, сегрегированных интерфейсов - один большой fat интерфейс

Comment: приходите в местный чат - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow-- - он более приспособлен к ведению длинных обсуждений.

Comment: Ваша имплементация `FilteringEnumeratorEx` неверна. Представьте себе, что у вас фильтр таков, что результирующая последовательность пуста. Тогда если вы создадите `FilteringEnumeratorEx` и запросите `HasNext`, вы получите `true`, что неправильно.

Comment: Семантика использования энумератора требует, чтобы первым вызывали MoveNext(). До этого позиция энумератора находится логически до 1ого элемента. В таком положении значения Current и HasNext/HasValue не имеют смысла. В случае с FilteringEnumeratorEx обращения и ответственность за реакцию будут переадресованы к вложенному энумератору. В случае же с FilteringEnumerator действительно вернется true. Но а какие еще возможны варианты? False - однозначно не правильно, т.к это признак конца. Так что учитывая семантику использования считаю, что все ок.

Comment: @РоманЕрмолин `HasNext` должен возвращать валидное значение до вызова `MoveNext()`, иначе смысла в таком `HasNext` никакого :) Смотрите - в вашем примере `MoveNext` ничего не возвращает. `HasNext` невалиден до первого вызова. Вы вызвали MoveNext на *потенциально пустой* последовательности. Как узнать, вычитался ли элемент? До вызова вы не знали, вычитается ли элемент - `HasNext` был невалиден. После вызова - вы тоже не знаете - `MoveNext` же void. Проверять Current на null? Так null - вполне валидное значение. Бросать исключение в `MoveNext()` - и все foreach в try/catch заворачивать?

Comment: @РоманЕрмолин вот серьезно - попробуйте написать код, имея ваш ваш интерфейс ISimpleEnumerator, корректно выведет на консоль последовательность строк, и не упадет, если ему достанется пустая коллекция. При этом придерживаясь вашего же решения, что до первого вызова `MoveNext` значение `HasNext` не определено.

Comment: @РоманЕрмолин и нет, isp нельзя записать как "много методов/функций, специально предназначенных для клиентов, лучше, чем один метод/функция общего назначения.". Потому что суть isp - клиенты **не должны видеть** неиспользуемые ими методы. А не "нужно больше методов, которые **все еще будет видеть каждый клиент**". Именно некорректное понимание вами isp и привело к появению этого вопроса.

Comment: @PashaPash Добавил тесты использования. Получилось все просто и логично. Не понимаю откуда такое враждебное отношение к HasNext. Оно принципиально ничем не отличается от Current. И то и другое кэшированные значение, хранящиеся в итераторе. В принципе в случае отказа от хранения состояния допустим даже SuperIterator. Другое дело, что в этом случае кэширование перекладывается на потребителя.

Comment: @РоманЕрмолин ну ок, вы переложили кэширование состояния в итератор, и заплатили за это тем, что клиент обязан делать проверку HasValue перед любым обращением к Current. Т.е. вы заставили всех клиентов зависеть от комплекта от трех методов (причем работа со всеми тремя-обязательна). Даже тех, которым хватает двух. Что усложнило код всех клиентов (а не только вашего парсера). Код клиентов явно стал сложнее (пусть даже на чуть-чуть). Это и есть нарушение ISP и его последствия. Идеальная реализация с точки зрения SOLID - это ISuperEnumerator (если бы не out). Чем дальше от него - тем хуже.

Comment: @РоманЕрмолин, и, кстати, ваше решение с HasValue не решает вашу же проблему с Parse - последний парсер в нем (ParseWord, или следующий за ним вызов) оставит последовательность на первом не подходящем ему символе, и `Parse` потеряет этот символ на следующей итерации.

Comment: @PashaPash Что касается ISP, то теперь мне начинает казаться, что к этому вопросу надо подходить с точки зрения того, кто же ответственен за хранение последних полученных значений из MoveNext и Current. Является ли это ответственностью энумератора или самого клиента. На данный момент Current хранится в энумераторе, а MoveNext на клиенте. Вполне возможно ответ зависит от того, на сколько толстую функциональность мы возлжим на сервис перебора. В своем парсере у меня была задумка все скинуть на энумератор.

Comment: @PashaPash После добавления HasValue я могу в любой момент спросить у энумератора есть ли в нем значение Current. И тогда мне уже не важна структура парсера. Каждый кусок последовательности парсит свой метод. На входе метода мы стоим на начале куска, а при выходе из метода стоим на начале следующего куска. Внешний метод Parse вообще не будет в цикле делать MoveNext. Ему надо будет его сделать только 1 раз для сдвига с -1ой позиции. А если сюда еще добавляется возможность клонирования энумератора с целью отката, то получается вообще все в шоколаде!

Comment: @РоманЕрмолин ну ок, отлично - и на выходе мы получаем (1) станадартный enumerator имеет сокращенный интерфейс, потому что этого достаточно для большинства клиентов (ISP соблюдено). (2) конкретно для парсера этого интерфейса недостаточно, итератор должен нести так же ответственность за кэширование. (3). вы можете написать обертку поверх любого стаднартного энумератора, в ответственность которой будет входить *только* кэширование HasNext/HasValue, а не вмешивать его в энумератор или парсер (SRP). SOLID в действии.

Comment: @РоманЕрмолин конретно это решение и применили разработчики парсера C#. У них эта тройка класов Parser + TextWindow + SourceText. и все в шоколоаде. А если вы при применении SOLID к той же проблеме получаете "дописать код всех клиентов (минус isp), дописать код во все реализации ради одной ответственности (минус srp)" - то это не совсем solid.

Answer (score 6):

В `ParseWord` вы обращаетесь к `enumerator.Current` без предварительного вызова `enumerator.MoveNext` - и, строго говоря, состояние `enumerator.Current` у вас при этом не определено. Т.е. `ParseWord` надеется, что кто-то заранее, до него, привел `enumerator` в валидное состояние.

---

По результатам обсуждения в комментариях:

Вы воспринимаете принцип ISP как "разделять методы на несколько". Это не совсем верное толкование. Суть метода ISP на примере Enumerator-а.

1. Есть какой-то класс, который умеет

   - перемещаться вперед (`MoveNext`).
   - возвращать текущий элемент (`Current`).
   - предсказывать, есть ли в последовательности еще один элемент (`HasNext`).
2. Есть две категории кода (клиентов), использующего этот объект:

   - Клиенты А - им нужно только шагать вперед и читать текущий элемент.
   - Клиенты Б - им нужно шагать вперед, читать текущий элемент, и знать возможно ли прочитать следующий.

Так вот, принцип ISP утверждает, что этот объект должен предоставлять два раздельных (сегрегированных) интерфейса.

- Интерфейс А, который предоставляется клиентам А - `MoveNext` + `Current`
- Интерфейс Б, который предоставляется клиентам Б - `MoveNext` + `Current` + `HasNext`

Делается это ради того, чтобы клиенты А не зависели от интерфейса, часть которого они не используют. Дословно, определение принципа:

> Client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use.

Применительно к вашему примеру - клиенты А, которые не используют `HasNext`, не должны зависеть от интерфейса, в которых есть метод `HasNext`.

Так вот, `IEnumerator` - это интерфейс для клиентов категории A. Стандартного интерфейса для клиентов категории Б - нет. Соответственно, нет его реализации в стандартных энумераторах.

Вы написали код клиента категории Б. Подставили в него класс, который реализует только интерфейс категории А (он и не собирался реализовать интерфейс для Б!). Естественно, это вызывает некоторые *неудобства*. Но к нарушению ISP это никакого отношения не имеет - проблема вызвана использованием конкретного класса не по назначению.

---

Любой код, использующий `IEnumerable`, не должен делать предположений о состоянии последовательности. Т.е. он должен сначала вызывать `MoveNext`, а потом уже - Current. На практике это означает что вы не сможете использовать один и тот же элемент `Current` в нескольких методах - что делает `IEnumerable` в чистом его виде неприменимым при парсинге.

Вам стоит сделать обертку поверх `IEnumerable`, которая кэшировала бы результат последнего вызова `MoveNext`. Именно так это решено, например, [в лексере C#](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/faddd31a6bfc066861c2c45597dcb14484af49d4/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Parser/Lexer.cs#L406).

В нем используется обертка [`SlidingTextWindow`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/56f605c41915317ccdb925f66974ee52282609e7/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Parser/SlidingTextWindow.cs), позволяющаяя, при необходимости, отмотать назад:

```
/// Keeps a sliding buffer over the SourceText of a file for the lexer. Also
/// provides the lexer with the ability to keep track of a current "lexeme"
/// by leaving a marker and advancing ahead the offset. The lexer can then
/// decide to "keep" the lexeme by erasing the marker, or abandon the current
/// lexeme by moving the offset back to the marker.
```

И первое же, что в ней объявлено - это признак конца файла. С очень подробным комментарием, посвященным именно вашей проблеме:

```
/// <summary>
/// In many cases, e.g. PeekChar, we need the ability to indicate that there are
/// no characters left and we have reached the end of the stream, or some other
/// invalid or not present character was asked for. Due to perf concerns, things
/// like nullable or out variables are not viable. Instead we need to choose a
/// char value which can never be legal.
/// 
/// In .NET, all characters are represented in 16 bits using the UTF-16 encoding.
/// Fortunately for us, there are a variety of different bit patterns which
/// are *not* legal UTF-16 characters. 0xffff (char.MaxValue) is one of these
/// characters -- a legal Unicode code point, but not a legal UTF-16 bit pattern.
/// </summary>
public const char InvalidCharacter = char.MaxValue;
```

Т.е. они решили проблему приведением `Current` в заведомо невалидное состояние + проверками вида `TextWindow.PeekChar == SlidingTextWindow.InvalidCharacter` в вызывающем коде.

Comment: Не совсем понятно из чего следует, что каждый метод должен сначала делать шаг, а затем уже читать. Если предположить, что за одним токеном (не совсем понимаю, что именно имеется ввиду под этим, но предполагаю некую последовательность символов) следует другой, то дочитав один токен мы окажемся в начале другого. В моем примере, не дочитав до пробела, мы не поймем, что слово закончилось. Т.о. анализ слова(токена) заканчивается в тот момент, когда мы оказываемся на "чужом" токене. Т.о. выйдя из метода анализа токена мы стоим на следующем. Именно из этого следует, что делать шаг не получится.

Comment: Возможно тут стоило бы уточнить, что для публичного метода да, состояние итератора может быть относительно любое и в идеале надо сделать сначала Reset+MoveNext. Но если мы говорим о приватных методах сильно интегрированных между собой, то думаю тут скорее всего все зависит от соглашения, которое принято в логике класса.

Comment: @РоманЕрмолин вот именно потому, что вам нужно читать символы и отматывать назад - чистый IEnumerable вам не подходит. Т.е. если вам нужно что-то вроде `IEnumerable` + `HasNext` - то возьмите и напишите его сами. Странно ожидать от общего интерфейса в стандартной библиотеке чего-то, чего в нем просто нет.

Comment: @РоманЕрмолин если коротко - то SOLID нарушает не IEnumerable, а ваш класс, который одновременно занимается разбором токенов + слежением за состоянием последовательности. Вам просто надо взять и вынести отслеживание/"получение признака достижения конца последовательности" в отдельный класс-обертку поверх IEnumerable. Т.е. вы ждете что IEnumerable будет и вычитывать элементы и отслеживать признак конца последовательности (что нарушит S). На самом деле IEnumerable просто вычитывает элементы. Все остальное - не его дело.

Comment: Я имел ввиду вот что: Принцип разделения интерфейса (Interface segregation principle) - много интерфейсов, специально предназначенных для клиентов, лучше, чем один интерфейс общего назначения. Применительно к MoveNext - метод делает одновременно 2 вещи: шаг и возвращает признак конца. А согласно принципу ISP должно быть 2 отдельных метода. В доказательство даже привел пример, где действительно возникают из-за этого проблемы.

Comment: @РоманЕрмолин MoveNext не возвращает признак конца коллекции. Он *пытается* сделать шаг и отчитывается об результате этой попытки. ISP вообще не имеет ничего общего с разделением метода на два. Суть ISP - если у вас есть объект, который умеет и идти вперед, и трекать конец, и есть две категории клиентов - одним нужно и идти вперед,  и знать о конце, второй - только идти вперед, то ваш объект должет предоставлять два различных интерфейса - один с трекингом конца, второй - без. Т.е. интерфейс разделяется на *два интерфейса*. Ваш пример не имеет с этим ничего общего.

Comment: @РоманЕрмолин вы взяли объект, который реализует один интерфейс, и пытаетесь его исользовать не по назначению. И при этом делаете вывод,  что для соблюдения ISP вам нужно добавить в интерфейс новый метод. При том, применение ISP должно увеличивать количество интерфейсов, уменьшая количество методов в каждом из них. Если вы применяее ISP и получаете увеличение количества методов - то это не ISP, а что-то другое :)

Comment: Значит у нас с Вами разное понимание принципа ISP.

Comment: @РоманЕрмолин возможно. Осталось выяснить, какое же из них общепринятое, а какое - совсем не isp. Смотрите: http://www.oodesign.com/interface-segregation-principle.html. там есть пример применения. Был один интерфейс с двумя методами,  стало два с одним. **Instead of one fat interface many small interfaces are preferred** based on groups of methods, each one serving one submodule.

Answer (score 3):

Хороший интерфейс берётся далеко не с потолка. Хороший интерфейс придумывается так, чтобы с ним было легко работать, и чтобы имплементация его не приводила к ошибкам. Нарушение любого из этих правил ведёт к бесполезности интерфейса.

---

Модификация интерфейса `IEnumerator<T>`, предлагаемая в вопросе, не выбрана разработчиками C# потому, что она *намного хуже* для имплементаторов, чем текущий интерфейс.

Дело в том, что предлагаемый вами метод `HasHext` *требует мутации состояния*, что приведёт к проблемам при попытке композиции нескольких последовательностей.

Пример: пусть энумератор обладает интерфейсом

```
public interface IEnumerator<T>
{
    T Current { get; }
    bool MoveNext();
    bool HasNext { get; }
    void Reset();
}
```

Попробуем заимплементировать LINQ-оператор `Where`. Для `HasNext` нам придётся в реальности вычитывать элементы из последовательности и кэшировать их! Поехали.

Стандартное начало:

```
public class FilteringEnumerator<T>
{
    IEnumerator<T> wrapped;
    Func<T, bool> filter;
    public FilteringEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> wrapped, Func<T, bool> filter)
    {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
        this.filter = filter;
    }
```

Посмотрим, как будет выглядеть `MoveNext`. Мы должны будем проверить, есть ли в внутренней последовательности значения, проходящие фильтр. Для этого нам придётся эти значения фактически прочитать, и закешировать, на случай, если будет вызван `MoveNext`. Теперь, если закешированное значение *уже есть*, нужна специальная логика.

```
    bool cacheOK = false;
    T cache;

    public bool HasNext
    { 
        get
        {
            if (cacheOK)
                return true;
            while (wrapped.MoveNext())
            {
                if (filter(wrapped.Current))
                {
                    cache = wrapped.Current;
                    cacheOK = true;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Теперь `Current`. Мы не можем просто вернуть `wrapped.Current`, потому что внутренняя последовательность могла уже убежать вперёд. Поэтому нам нужно «материальное» свойство.

```
    public T Current { get; private set; }
```

Теперь `MoveNext`. Если у нас есть закешированное значение, то просто отдаём его. Иначе нам придётся искать дальше.

```
    bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (!cacheOK)
        {
            var result = HasNext;
            if (!result)
                return false;
        }
        // тут у нас есть значение в кеше, вытягиваем его
        Current = cache;
        cacheOK = false;
        return true;
    }

    void Reset() { throw new NotSupportedException(); } 
}
```

Правда, сложная логика?

Для сравнения, смотрите, что будет с обычным определением.

```
public interface IEnumerator<T>
{
    T Current { get; }
    bool MoveNext();
    void Reset();
}
```

То же стандартное начало:

```
public class FilteringEnumerator<T>
{
    IEnumerator<T> wrapped;
    Func<T, bool> filter;
    public FilteringEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> wrapped, Func<T, bool> filter)
    {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
        this.filter = filter;
    }
```

И имплементация:

```
    T Current => wrapped.Current;
    bool MoveNext()
    {
        while (wrapped.MoveNext())
            if (filter(wrapped.Current))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    void Reset() { throw new NotSupportedException(); } 
}
```

Видите разницу?

---

Итераторы с lookahead практически никогда не нужны в реальности. В тех немногих случаях, когда они действительно нужны (например, имплементация токенизатора), несложно заимплементировать lookahead самостоятельно:

```
class Lookehead<T> : IDisposable
{
    IEnumerator<T> en;
    public Lookehead(IEnumerator<T> en)
    {
        this.en = en;
        MoveForward();
    }

    public bool HasValue { get; private set; }
    public T Value { get; private set; }

    public void MoveForward()
    {
        HasValue = en.MoveNext();
        if (HasValue)
            Value = en.Current;
    }

    public void Dispose() => en.Dispose();
}
```

При этом ваш код получается очень простым:

```
public class Parser : IDisposable
{
    public Parser(IEnumerable<char> seq)
    {
        lookahead = new Lookehead<char>(seq.GetEnumerator());
    }

    Lookahead<char> lookahead;

    public void Dispose() => lookahead.Dispose();

    void Parse()
    {
        while (lookahead.HasValue)
        {
            if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(lookahead.Value)) // пробелы пропускаем
                ParseWord(); // мы за концом слова или текст завершён
            else
                lookahead.MoveForward();
        }
    }

    void ParseWord()
    {
        // предусловие: если мы тут, то lookahead.HasValue == true
        // читаем пока буквы
        while (lookahead.HasValue && char.IsLetter(lookahead.Value))
        {
            // ...

            lookahead.MoveForward();
        }
        // постусловие: если мы тут, то lookahead.HasValue == false или
        // lookahead.Value - не буква
    }
}
```

Comment: На счет Lookehead и Parser: именно об этом я и говорю, что разделение метода MoveNext на 2: MoveForward и HasValue (название больше понравилось, чем HasNext, спс за подсказку) позволяет сделать код более понятным и легким. Метод Parse сразу стал работать и не зависеть от хитросплетений Move-ов во вложенных методах. Ну разве так не удобнее, чем с MoveNext? (риторический вопрос)

Comment: @РоманЕрмолин: В том-то и дело, что удобно только в этом специальном случае: написании парсера. В практически всех остальных случаях эта функциональность не нужна. И хуже того, наличие этой функциональности повсюду очень затруднило бы имплементацию. Поэтому её нигде и нету, а при случае написать обёртку, как вы видите, вопрос двух минут.

Comment: Для меня совсем не очевидно, что затруднило бы имплементацию. Сейчас энумератор кэширует только само значение, что позволяет вызвать Current, а если бы еще кэшировал признак перехода, то и свойство HasNext было бы доступно. Если вообще убрать какое-либо кэширование, то получаем bool MoveNext(out T current); Разница лишь в том на кого перекладывается ответственность за кэширование.

Comment: @РоманЕрмолин: Ну у меня ж как раз пример гораздо более сложной имплементации `Where` для интерфейса с `HasHext` (`FilteringEnumerator`). Посмотрите!

Comment: Посмотрел. Только сейчас до меня дошло, что мы говорим о разных вещах! Я взял название HasNext из Java, но подразумевал не следующее, которое еще не хранится в Current, а всего лишь запомненное из MoveNext. Его можно назвать HasValue или LastMoveNext. Да то, что Вы реализовали довольно сложная штука и я бы назвал это предчтением. Даже мысли не было об этом :) Так что прошу пересмотреть свой взгляд на предлагаемую мной идею. Она заключается лишь в том, что кроме Current надо еще кэшировать и то, что возвращает MoveNext(). И только.

Comment: @РоманЕрмолин: Ага, теперь понял. Та семантика, которую реализовал я, взята из Java. Там стандартный цикл по контейнеру выглядит как `while (it.hasNext()) print(en.next())`, причём именно `.next()` осуществляет продвижение (а `hasNext()` лишь подглядывает вперёд). В вашей семантике поле скорее называется `IsCurrentValid`, если я правильно понимаю. Дайте подумать о ней.

Comment: Да тут особо и не о чем думать. В моем примере с Parse и ParseWord происходит переход энумератора из одной области видимости в другую. Т.о. bool, возвращаемый из MoveNext теряется, а заново спросить у энумератора не получится, т.к. он не кэшируется в нем в отличие от Current. Передавать в качестве out параметра мягко говоря криво. На мой взгляд отвечать на вопрос прошли мы всю последовательность или нет должен именно сам итератор, ему должно быть виднее. Пока альтернативы не вижу. Парсер хотелось бы ограничить очень жестко - только разбор и ничего более.

Comment: @РоманЕрмолин: Ну, для конкретно нужд парсера достаточно, например, Lookahead из моего ответа. Сам по себе Enumerator, таки да, не подходит. А на lookahead'е на один символ парсер прекрасно строится (у меня была ссылка на пример токенизатора где-то в комментариях).